# How to create 2 folders in same repository?

Tags: git, github, stm32

I am working on a project that contains:

1. Code in Angular (workspace: Visual Studio Code)
2. Code in C (workspace: STM32CubeIDE)

Is there a convenient way in github to store both types of code in the same repository but in different folders?

Comment: Create two directories? Not sure I understand what exactly the problem is

Comment: @Mureinik , Thanks for your answer! and is it possible to do a pull/push for one of the directories and not to the other?

Comment: Git does not pull / push directories. It does not deal in directories at all. It deals in files. But it does not push / pull files either. It push / pulls commits. And usually the way you tell it which commits to push / pull is as a _branch_.

Comment: So with the help of the branches I can instruct in which directory to make the commit? @matt

Comment: I don't recommend anything because I don't see what the problem is. Who cares if the folders contain different languages?

Comment: Commits are not made "in a directory". You work. You "add" the new versions of the files you worked on. You commit. Every commit contains all your files. It is a snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one repository, any commit would be for the all repository (all the folders)

You might consider adding and committing only files from one folder.
And then adding and committing files from the other folder.

But that a process only you can follow: Git itself does not care about folders when doing the actual commit, which is a snapshot of the *all* repository.

Only [submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules) (meaning 3 repositories, one parent referencing two submodules, one repository per language) would come close of "storing both types of code in the same repository but in different folders".
Except your main repository would not "store" per se, rather reference/point to other repositories.